# Swapping indices with values in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, swap, indices

(No, this is not a homework assignment nor a contest, even though it might look like one.)

I have a list `A` in Python that contains the numbers `range(0, len(A))`. The numbers are not in order, but all of them exist in the list.

I'm looking for a simple way to build a list `B` where the indices and values have been swapped, i.e. a list that, for each integer `n`, contains the position of `n` in `A`.

Example:

```
A = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
B = [0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

I can put the code to generate `B` either separately or in the code that generates `A`. In particular, here's how I generate `A`:

```
A = [value(i) for i in range(length)]
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to decorate each value with their index, sorting with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) on the values, and then un-decorate again to extract the indices in value order:

```
[i for i, v in sorted(enumerate(A), key=lambda iv: iv[1])]
```

This has a O(NlogN) time complexity because we used sorting.

Demo:

```
>>> A = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
>>> [i for i, v in sorted(enumerate(A), key=lambda iv: iv[1])]
[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

We can also use a pre-built list to assign indices to for a O(N) solution:

```
B = [0] * len(A)
for i, v in enumerate(A):
    B[v] = i
```

Demo:

```
>>> B = [0] * len(A)
>>> for i, v in enumerate(A):
...     B[v] = i
... 
>>> B
[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

This is probably the better option if time complexity is of a big issue; for N = 100 the sorting approach will take about 461 steps vs. 100 for the pre-built list approach.

Comment: I don't see any reason to ever use the `sorted` solution

Answer (score 6):

How about assigning to the pre-allocated B:

```
>>> A = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
>>> B = [0] * len(A)
>>> for k, v in enumerate(A): B[v] = k
>>> B
[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

That would be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]

B = [None]*len(A)

for i, x in enumerate(A):
    B[x] = i

print B
```

res: `[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]`

Comment: wrapping `[None]*len(A)` in `list(...)` achieves nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is very naive;

`[ [ x[0] for x in enumerate(A) if x[1] == i][0] for i in range(len(A)) ]`

This works perfect,

```
[A.index(A.index(i)) for i in A]
```

This is **better**;

```
[A.index(i[0]) for i in enumerate(A)]
```

This one **beats** the other;

```
[A.index(i) for i in range(len(A))]
```

Proof;

```
import random as r
for l in [ r.sample(range(5),5) for n in range(5) ]:
    A = l
    B = [A.index(A.index(i)) for i in A]
    print "A is : ", A
    print "B is : ", B
    print "Are B's elements indices of A? : ", A == [B.index(B.index(i)) for i in B]
    print
```

Comment: This is **hugely** inefficient. This is a O(N^2) quadratic approach; if you do this to a list with 100 elements you'll be making 100.000 comparisons. For a list with 1.000.000 elements, that'll be 1.000.000.000.000 comparisons.

Comment: @martijn-pieters thanks for the comments. I've updated my post, any more comments?

Comment: `list.index()` is *still a O(N) step*. It looks like just one command to you but Python still will need to scan the list to find the first match and return the index.